# Config file in Symfony that is global to the project and can be used in models?

Tags: php, symfony1

Is there a config file in Symfony 1.4 where you can place custom values that is accessible to your models? I was using app.yml in my frontend app so far but models are common for all applications in the project, so this won't work at the model level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an app.yml file in the main project config/ folder - symfony will be able to use any values defined in it in the standard way. Just make sure the names don't conflict with anything in the app.yml files for each actual app.

Comment: Why is conflict a problem? The config cascade will take care of it - the app (or module) level will overwrite the project level.